# render albedo (color passe without shadow)

Tags: render-passes

I am trying to render the albedo of a mesh with a material, I have managed to get a flat render without lights and shadows by using the diffuse color passe, but the color are not the same as the one used in the material of the mesh.

Here is my setup:

- 3D view:
  A sphere (here you can see his material thanks to the viewport shading set to material) and a light (to test if there are shadows in the render[image]
- UV / Image:
  Each face of the sphere is unwrapped on that square with two color
  [image]
- Shader node:[image]
- Render layer:
  the passes I have checked
  [image]
- Compositing node:
  [image]
- Result:
  As you can see the color are not the same as the one of the UV/Image
  [image]

Here is a comparison between the color of the image I have used to texture the mesh (on the left) and the color I get from the diffuse color passe (on the right)[image]

Does someone know how to fix that problem or why the color shift ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as unclear, because (1) I [can't reproduce](https://i.imgur.com/a0wN5dj.png) it and (2) the last to images don't seem to relate. I'd suggest you reproduce the problem in a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and upload that file here.

Comment: Here I have edited my question and made my exemple simpler, I hope it is now easier to understand my problem. As I see in your comment Leander, your diffuse color is the same as the one of the checker texture. I don't understand why I have a difference. @Leander

Comment: I have experienced this disparity as well and am not certain of the cause. I see that the color space for your texture node (third image) is "Linear" (typical setting). Check if your render settings, i.e. the color space, is something unexpected. By default it should be Filmic. This may desaturate colors slightly. Try changing that, just for the bake.

Comment: really, instead of voting to close every question we don't understand, we should just ask for more info in the comments, or wait for someone else who might be able to help.

Comment: @Millard - this is exactly what a close vote is. There are many cases on BSE where people drop in, ask some vague question, then leave if nobody answers within 10 minutes. The close vote is a heads-up to people. If the question gets improved and gathers enough attention, it can also be reopened.

Comment: ok, that makes more sense.

Comment: "*really, instead of voting to close every question we don't understand, we should just ask for more info in the comments, or wait for someone else who might be able to help.*" @Millard you are now formally appointed as the official "asker for clarification" for every single unclear or vague question posted henceforth. Lets see how long your energy lasts.

Comment: After the first comment of Leander I have edited the question to make it more clear, the comment of hatinacat2000 help me to solve the problem and I answered my question in order to help if someone face the same issue. But I have seen that some of you voted to close the question, I am new to blenderstack and I don't know what I must do. Should I delete it or will it be done automatically if enough people vote to close my question ?

Comment: Closed questions don't necessarily get deleted, see it instead as an opportunity to improve your post. Since you have edited it I think it can even be reopened. As for your problem it seems like another case of color management

Comment: yeah, don't delete it, if a question can be helpful to someone later on, it shouldn't get deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Leander show in the picture of his comment there shouldn't be a problem with the passes or the nodes I have used and how I have connected them.

As hatinacat2000 suggest, I get better result by setting the color space to linear

[image]

Here is the texture on the left and the render of the albedo on the right a bit
better but not the same:

[image]

In fact the color of the albedo where shifted because of the High contrast setting (in the Look of the color Management), by changing it to none The color of the albedo are the same as the one of the texture

[image]

[image]