# How can I render albedo pass (color without shadow)?

Tags: rendering, render-passes, viewlayers

I have tried to follow [these instructions](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/149612/render-albedo-color-passe-without-shadow) but I am not able to recreate the steps in blender 2.8. I have asked [this question before](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/154104/how-to-render-a-new-texture-image-from-scene?noredirect=1#comment262139_154104) and one of the steps was to set the "diffuse" setting to "color":

[image]

But I cannot find this on Blender 2.8:

[image]

So how can I render an albedo using blender 2.8?

Answer (score 2):

<del>The diffuse color render pass is not available in Eevee.</del>

Diffuse color render pass (AOV) is available for Cycles as well as for Eevee. Go to *Properties > View Layer > Passes > Light* and enable Diffuse *(Color)*:

[image]

Also see the manual: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/layers/passes.html#light

Comment: I have done this, but when I go to render (render > render image) the render is still affected by the world brightness, which changes the colors of the texture. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you have to go to the compositor and save the render pass as a separate image using a file output node or connect the render pass socket to the composite node, if you don't need the "normal" render.

Comment: Thanks! I still have a problem though. The diffuse color render pass [still looks washed out compared to the original texture](https://imgur.com/jhf5um4) even though I have "look" set to "none" and color space set to linear AND "diffuse" light set to "color". If it helps, [here is the blend file](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=52411).

Comment: oops! [Here is the texture I'm using](http://pasteall.org/pic/d88fc6095abb339bb0e2c09be1cadf3e)

Comment: @brockmann Thanks for the update.