# Diffuse render pass looks different from original texture

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, compositing-nodes, render-passes

I have tried to follow [these instructions](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/149612/render-albedo-color-passe-without-shadow) on how to get a diffuse render pass of a brick texture that exactly replicates the original colors of the texture. But even with all the settings in place I get a render pass that looks slightly off from the original texture as you can see here:

[image]

I was wondering if there is some other setting that I've missed? I'm using blender 2.8. If you're interested, [here is the blend file](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=52419) too. All help is appreciated!

Comment: Why not bake it? It's definitely a color management related thing, my guess is that left image is in sRGB and right in Linear color modes.